# Node.Js: Resource Interpreted as Font but Transferred with MIME Type text/html

Tags: node.js, mime, font-awesome

The icons on my website, which is being served up by Node.Js, are not rendering, and I am seeing the error indicated in the title. I am using this script for my server...
https://github.com/joeeames/AngularFundamentalsFiles/blob/master/web-server.js

Below [line 98](https://github.com/joeeames/AngularFundamentalsFiles/blob/master/web-server.js#L98) I added...

```
'woff':'application/font-woff'
```

I also...

```
npm install mime
```

But nothing I do seems to work. Does anyone know how how to solve this problem? The specific error from the console is...

```
Resource interpreted as Font but transferred with MIME type text/html: "https://<my_site>/bower_components/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.1.0".
```

I see similar errors for TTF and SVG types.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It probably means that you are requesting a resource that doesn't have a matching route, so the server is sending down the index page. If you look at the contents of the request in the developer tools of your browser, you should see that it is an html document that is being returned. You need to diagnose why what you are requesting doesn't have a matching route besides the default route that serves up the index.html page.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what the problem was. Sorry, meant to answer this question, but you beat me to it! I used Bower to include font-awesome in my project and Grunt to build it. The font-awesome CSS specifies the location of the fonts, but that file was not included in my Grunt build artifact, so it was returning a 404, which the NodeJS server would send back as type text/html. Using font-awesome via CDN was the solution I chose.