# Font .woff 404 not found on azure node js web app

Tags: css, node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service, font-awesome

I have this fonts present on my `wwwroot` as shown on my nodejs app's console :
[image]

I have this usage on my `css` :

```
@font-face {
    font-family: myFont;
    src: url(resources/font/Montserrat-Bold.woff) format("truetype");
    font-weight: bold;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: myFont;
    src: url(resources/font/Montserrat-Light.woff) format("truetype");
    font-weight: 300;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: myFont;
    src: url(resources/font/Montserrat-Regular.woff) format("truetype");
    font-weight: 400;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: myFont;
    src: url(resources/font/Montserrat-SemiBold.woff) format("truetype");
    font-weight: 500;
}
```

---

```
html, body{
    font-family: myFont;
    font-weight: 300;
}
```

---

It's working perfectly on **localhost** but im getting this error from the version I uploaded on **azure**.
[image]

Comment: See similar SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25452126/node-js-resource-interpreted-as-font-but-transferred-with-mime-type-text-html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please access the console of Kudu tool at `https://<your-webapp-name>.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole` and check the `web.config` & `server.js` files below if using Express framework. And I think you need to add the prefix symbol `/` for the url `resources/font/...` in the css file.

Fig 1. The `web.config` & `server.js` at the path `wwwroot`

[image]

Fig 2. The rewrite rule for static content in the `web.config`

[image]

Fig 3. The express static route configuration in the `server.js`

[image]

Comment: Those who are using custom publish build tools,please note that you need to include web.config file in the root of your publish folder. This way azure will pick it up from and place in wwwroot. 

This is for CI process : https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/play-by-play-angular-2-app-deployment-azure-git-john-papa-shayne-boyer

Answer (score 4):

There might be an issue with the IIS server node that it does not understand your font mimetype. To explain it to how to serve proper font you need to:

1. download you auto generated web.config file using KuDo debugging console.
2. add these lines to proper place in that file:

   `<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
       <staticContent>
           <remove fileExtension=".otf" />
           <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
           <mimeMap fileExtension=".otf" mimeType="font/opentype" />
           <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-woff" />
   </staticContent>
   </system.websServer>
   </configuration>`

Hope this helps.